# Dealing with bounced emails

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, bounce

Currently we are using AWS SES to send an authentication email to the user. (This email is not related to the usual login/register authentication, it's our own)

The email address is entered by the user and we are sending one and only one email per email address.

This leads to many bounced emails and AWS suspended our service (around 9000 sent emails and 15% bounce rate).

My question:

How to deal with this problem? Users will mistype their email all the time. There is no way to verify if an email is valid without sending an actual email, right? That means that all SMTP providers will suspend our ability to send emails sooner or later.

Using nodejs to send the email but that is not really relevant I think.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is irrelevant to programming

Comment: @Vega
Stackoverflow is not strictly about progrmaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the bounces by adding a sns topic and subscribe to it to get more information when bounces emails. (It's not always because of faulty email)
2. Ask users to enter their email address twice
3. There are some services out there that you can pass email addresses to that will give you a classification as to how likely the address is to be a “good” address

Here is a document from AWS which describes your problem:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/what-do-i-do-if-my-registration-emails-themselves-have-high-bounce-rates/

Comment: Hello!  


Thank you for the suggestions. The double input is definitely a good idea I think we will implement it.  


In the end we changed to SendGrid because it automatically shows the bounced email addresses and their suspension policy (and support) seemed better.  


Unfortunately all of the bounced email are because of user typos. These addresses are student emails so it's automatically created (sometimes with lot of random numbers) and students don't really use it everyday so they forget it...

Comment: Sendgrid has more out of the box I agree. If you are allowed you compare with the university email system which email are legit.